# Convert grade to value in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create a gradesheet using google sheets, each assignment grades are entered as letters (A thru F). Each grade is given a numerical value - decided dynamically at the end of course.

I want to create a gradesheet in which I can enter each students grades as letters and in the end while calculating the final grade each letter is converted to a number and totalled.

Is there anyway to do this in google sheets.

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you set up a little table as highlighted in the image and name it (I chose GTable):

[image: SO39336369 example]

then apply a lookup formula such as:

```
=vlookup(A1,GTable,2,0)
```

If you do so without some kind of table then you may be trying to fix formulae each time the dynamic decision is changed, and fixing a table may be easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a second gradesheet based off of the original gradesheet, but instead of letter values, each cell would have something like

```
=IF(B2="A",100,IF(B2="B",90,IF(B2="C",80,IF(B2="D",70,IF(B2="F",60,0)))))
```

In this case, `B2` is the cell corresponding to the original gradesheet, so each cell in the new gradesheet would correspond to a cell in the original gradesheet. You can then replace the hardcoded numbers with values from the spreadsheet or expand the conditional to cover more letter grades, and use this new table to calculate the final grade.